# Unable to remove zipped file after unzipping

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I'm attempting to remove a zipped file after unzipping the contents on windows. The contents can be stored in a folder structure in the zip. I'm using the `with` statement and thought this would close the file-like object (`source` var) and zip file. I've removed lines of code relating to saving the source file.

```
import zipfile
import os

zipped_file = r'D:\test.zip'

with zipfile.ZipFile(zipped_file) as zip_file:
    for member in zip_file.namelist():
        filename = os.path.basename(member)
        if not filename:
            continue
        source = zip_file.open(member)

os.remove(zipped_file)
```

The error returned is:

```
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'D:\\test.zip'
```

I've tried:

- looping over the `os.remove` line in case it's a slight timing issue
- Using close explicitly instead of the `with` statment
- Attempted on local C drive and mapped D Drive

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried adding a short delay before the remove? e.g. `time.sleep(2)`

Comment: yes tried it and still same error.

Comment: did you try `del zip_file` before the `os.remove` ?

Comment: you could change your code to pass a file object (rather than the path) to the `ZipFile` constructor and then explicitly close that

Comment: @HarryPotfleur yes tried and still the same

Comment: Did you try adding a `source.close()`? If you `print source.closed` outside the with  it will show it is still open which may cause your issue on windows

Comment: Oops, I didn't read the code properly before making my previous comment. Sorry. The `source` zipfile object has to be closed via its `.close()` method.

Comment: tried `del zip_file` and `source.close()` and `sleep` - makes no difference.

Comment: This is probably windows specific behavior. On other OSes you can remove files while they're open anyway.

Comment: @Stagg,  where are you calling `source.close()`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I've tried it in the `for` loop, outside the `for` loop and outside the `with`. Basically everywhere.

Comment: What happens if you just use `zip_file.extractall`?

Comment: @JamesKent yes using a file object instead of a file string works when passed into the ZipFile constructor! Thanks. Do you want to post an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

instead of passing in a string to the `ZipFile` constructor, you can pass it a file like object:

```
import zipfile
import os

zipped_file = r'D:\test.zip'

with open(zipped_file, mode="r") as file:
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(file)
    for member in zip_file.namelist():
        filename = os.path.basename(member)
        if not filename:
            continue
        source = zip_file.open(member)

os.remove(zipped_file)
```

Comment: documentation for behaviour here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Python 3 on Windows 7. I get `raise BadZipFile`. I suspect I may have a gzip file, not a zip file. Could you please show the corresponding code for a gzip file?

Comment: I may have made mistake in the above post, try changing the mode to rb instead

Comment: @JamesKent: Still no joy. I'm not sure it is a gzip file - it may just be an ordinary zip file.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you then, this code should open a regular zip file without issue, have ypu tried examining your file with other software to identify the compression?

Comment: @JamesKent: I think the problem was that LabVIEW (where I generated the zip file) was still open and hanging on to the file. See my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51617994/how-do-i-delete-a-gzip-file-in-windows-via-python-file-generated-in-labview.

Answer (score 2):

You are opening files inside the zip... which create a file lock on the whole zip file.  close the inner file open first... via source.close() at the end of your loop

```
import zipfile
import os

zipped_file = r'D:\test.zip'

with zipfile.ZipFile(zipped_file) as zip_file:
    for member in zip_file.namelist():
        filename = os.path.basename(member)
        if not filename:
            continue
        source = zip_file.open(member)
    source.close()

os.remove(zipped_file)
```

Comment: Works for me.  Without the source.close() line I get the error "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'D:\\test.zip'" on line 14.  Adding this line resolve this as there is no longer a file lock on the outer zip file test.zip due to the inner file (source = zip_file.open(member)) being left open.  Why open the inner file anyway? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to open the inner file as I copy the file out of the zip to the parent folder.         `target = file(os.path.join(unzip_location, filename), 'wb')`
        `with source, target:`
            `shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)`

Comment: you on python 2.7, windows 7?

Comment: @eryksun: Could you please expand your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try to [close](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.close) the zipfile before removing.

Comment: But according to the documentation the file should be closed when leaving the `with` statement.

Comment: `with` should clear up the resources. I tried close also, same error.

Answer (score 0):

you can do also like this, which works pretty good:

```
import os, shutil, zipfile

fpath= 'C:/Users/dest_folder'
path = os.getcwd()

for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith(".zip"):
        dirs = os.path.join(path, file)

if os.path.exists(fpath):
    shutil.rmtree(fpath)
_ = os.mkdir(fpath)

with open(dirs, 'rb') as fileobj:
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(fileobj)
    z.extractall(fpath)
    z.close()
os.remove(dirs)
```